# Table marked as crashed and repair failed

Tags: mysql, database, joomla-1.5

My Joomla 1.5.16 website has started to display the error below. I don't think this is a hack, and I can't find any evidence in the logs of someone trying to get in or any changes to files that shouldn't be there. Any advice appreciated.

> ```
> Table './patht/jos_users' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
>
> SQL=SELECT offers.*, categories.name AS catName, types.name AS typeName, levels.name AS
>  levelName, experiences.name AS experienceName, users.name AS contactName FROM 
> jos_neorecruit_offers AS offers LEFT JOIN jos_neorecruit_categories AS categories ON 
> offers.category = categories.id LEFT JOIN jos_neorecruit_types AS types ON offers.type = 
> types.id LEFT JOIN jos_neorecruit_levels AS levels ON offers.level = levels.id LEFT JOIN 
> jos_neorecruit_experiences AS experiences ON offers.experience = experiences.id LEFT JOIN 
> jos_users AS users ON offers.contact = users.id WHERE ( ( offers.access != '' AND 
> offers.access <= 0 ) OR ( offers.access = '' AND 1 <= 0 ) ) AND offers.published = 1 AND 
> categories.published = 1 AND ( offers.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR offers.publish_up 
> <= '2014-05-02 08:37' ) AND ( offers.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR 
> offers.publish_down >= '2014-05-02 08:37' ) ORDER BY offers.created_datetime DESC LIMIT 3
> ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might need to use MySQL to manually repair the table.

If you can run arbitrary MySQL on your server, run the `mysql` CLI and use:

```
REPAIR TABLE jos_users;
```

Alternatively, phpMyAdmin (supplied by many hosts to manage MySQL databases) allows you to repair tables through a GUI. To do so:

- Access phpMyAdmin and select the Joomla database from the left-hand panel
- Select the `jos_users` table (or whatever table needs repaired)
- Select **Operations** from the horizontal top menu
- Select **Repair table** from the links under **Table maintenance**

Comment: Repairing with MySQL seems to have done the trick, but I'm a bit concerned about why it happened in the first place..

Comment: Has it happened before? I sometimes get this on a very high-load J1.5 site, but usually on `jos_sessions`. It may be worth doing a full audit to check if you've been hacked, but otherwise it's likely just a transient error.

Comment: Not previously - the site doesn't have a high load, but it does have 22,000 users...

Comment: Just curious... when something like this does happen, what are the chances of data loss?